# Adding NA's to a vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector of prices:

```
foo <- c(102.25,102.87,102.25,100.87,103.44,103.87,103.00)
```

I want to get the percent change from x periods ago and, say, store it into another vector that I'll call log_returns.  I can't bind vectors foo and log_returns into a data.frame because the vectors are not the same length.  So I want to be able to append NA's to log_returns so I can put them in a data.frame.  I figured out one way to append an NA at the end of the vector:

```
log_returns <- append((diff(log(foo), lag = 1)),NA,after=length(foo))
```

But that only helps if I'm looking at percent change 1 period before.  I'm looking for a way to fill in NA's no matter how many lags I throw in so that the percent change vector is equal in length to the foo vector

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can store in a list instead

Comment: the answer below is nice, but more generally if you have a list of unequal length vectors, you can do something like `l <- list(1, 1:2, 1:5); data.frame(lapply(l, \`length<-\`, max(lengths(l))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use your own modification of diff:

```
mydiff <- function(data, diff){
  c(diff(data, lag = diff), rep(NA, diff))
}

mydiff(foo, 1)
[1]  0.62 -0.62 -1.38  2.57  0.43 -0.87    NA

data.frame(foo = foo,  diff = mydiff(foo, 3))

     foo  diff
1 102.25 -1.38
2 102.87  0.57
3 102.25  1.62
4 100.87  2.13
5 103.44    NA
6 103.87    NA
7 103.00    NA
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have an array with number 1 to 10 arranged in the matrix form, in which
The matrix contains Elements from 5 rows 2 columns & 2nd column to be assigned NA , #
then Making one 5*2 matrix of elements 1:10
[image]

```
Array_test=array(c(1:10),dim=c(5,2,1)) 
Array_test
Array_test[ ,2, ]=c(NA)# Defining 2nd column to get NA
Array_test
# Similarly to make only one element of the entire matrix be NA 
# let's say 4nd-row 2nd column to be made NA then
Array_test[4 ,2, ]=c(NA)
```